# Replacing numeric NAs and 0's with blank, and all values greater than 0 with "X"

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a dataframe `emissions` that looks like this (example):

```
CEDS_Sector                    Ammonia      Carbon Dioxide     ...
1A1a_Public Electricity         2528             NA
1A1b_Pet_refining               NA               NA
1A1c_Coke-ovens                 0.000           1467
...
```

`CEDS_Sector` is a factor, and all other columns are numeric.
If there is an `NA` or 0 entry, I want that cell to become blank. If there is a > 0 value, I want that cell to have an "X" in it, to look like this"

```
CEDS_Sector                    Ammonia      Carbon Dioxide     ...
1A1a_Public Electricity           X             
1A1b_Pet_refining              
1A1c_Coke-ovens                                   X
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `mutate_if()`:

```
library(dplyr) 

emissions %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x) | x == 0, 
                                           "",
                                           "X"))
```

Comment: thank you! I always forget about `mutate_if()`